# How to create timer in my games in cocos2dx using c++

Tags: c++, timer, cocos2d-x

I am developing games and facing problem with creating timer. I need some logic like time should start from 60 sec when it reach to 0 game should end. I am new to this platform.

Comment: google search, my friend -> http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/12050?r=12053

Comment: There are a number of ways to create timers and times events, maybe `std::thread` and writing a Timer class. I usually create a `std::vector` of `std::threads` and they all run at their proper intervals and I can get to them easily to manipulate. If you accepted more answers people provide they might give you more help.

Comment: I found this thread. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19607-is-there-any-simple-c-timer-around.html I tried, couldn't get it to work, but might help someone :-) Myself will try to sort it out using schedule like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually use the  scheduler for this, which you can use to call a method at fixed time intervals, like this:

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(Game::UpdateTimer),1.0f);
```

in this case it calls 'Game:UpdateTimer' once a second.  In update timer you'd just reduce your counter by one, and when it's reach zero stop the timer like this:

```
this->unschedule( schedule_selector(Game::UpdateTimer));
```

and add a method underneath to be called

```
void Game::UpdateTimer(float dt)
{

}
```